# Sending string over Serial port to dial up modem

Tags: vb.net, serial-port, dial-up

So, I'm not terribly familiar with Dial up commands, but what I've been tasked with is creating a back up to a paging application.  We're trying to make an application to dial the number, wait, then send the numeric page over the phone.  So, I have all the main components, where I seem to be having problems is with the actual string once the serial port is engaged and I have dial tone. The problem seems to be when I use the "," pause in the string, it just never keeps sending after that.  I need it to pause for the "," and then send the remaining numbers.

So for example "ADTD 5554444,1786"

So, we get the 5554444 to go, then pauses and never sends the rest over.  I hope this makes sense.

Comment: Have you tried implementing the pause yourself on the .net side instead of using the comma? I'd be curious whether it works, functionally, if you send the string in two pieces with a short wait in the middle. At the very least, that will tell you whether the problem is with the interpretation of the comma or something else

Comment: I thought about something like that, but I'm just not terribly familiar with the commands.  I tried it and it didn't work, but I may have done it wrong.  In the documentation I found it said about using a semi colon, then doing another writeline to the serial port with an ADT to continue, but I didn't get it to work.  But, again, I may have used the wrong commands.  While I'm from the time of Dial Up, I'm new to doing anything funky with it! lol

Comment: I don't have ADT's documentation, but if you try splitting it into two strings with a pause in the middle, careful with using the WriteLine() method. That is going to end your transmission with a terminator character, which many APIs interpret as the end of your command. Instead, I would try port.Write(), pause, port.WriteLine()

Comment: Ah, I will keep that in mind, could be why my first attempt failed.  I was just going of of MSDN's section on it, so that's what they went with.  I'll give those a shot and see how it goes!

Comment: Many years have passed since my last DialUp, but the commands started with "AT" (attention) and a Dial Tone (DTMF) was sent with DT (DialTone and a &C1&D2 configuration usually), so the command (was) ATDT *number*. ATDP for Pulse dial. With GSM/UMTS, you just send ATD *number* (no tones). Same sequence, anyway. The comma delay is configured with the S8 register. With PABX you can use the "@" Wait for Silence modifier.

Comment: Yeah, it's certainly going back in time for this project!  I will keep those tips in mind.  Thanks!